# Search list of names and their values from a file to another files?

Tags: csv, search

I have two .csv files. First file has one column of list of names and second file has sixty columns including names and their values in all columns. I am looking to search names from first file to their names and values from second file.

For example:

First file:

```
Column 1
Polaromonas
uncultured
Leptothrix
Clostridium
Methylocystis
```

Second file:

```
Column 1      Column 2    Column 3        Column 4    Column 5        Column 6
 NP                        NT                           CT
Methylocystis   34         Desulfonema      0           Methylocystis    23  
uncultured      67         Chlorobium       43          Clostridium      12
Clostridium     23         Rhodovulum       45          Rhodovulum       12
Leptothrix      32         Azohydromonas    12          Azohydromonas    45 
Polaromonas     21         Allochromatium   23          Allochromatium   0
```

Sample Output:

```
              NP      NT        CT
Polaromonas   21      0         0
uncultured    67      0         0
Leptothrix    32      0         0
Clostridium   23      43        12
Methylocystis 34      0         23
```

Comment: *sixty columns* - you meant **six** columns? Why this `NP      NT        CT` line should be printed?

Comment: The second file have sixty columns, here for example i am giving only six column....

Comment: NP NT and CT is just header ...so i just want to print for identification else i can add later manually.  ...

Comment: `Clostridium` does not have `43` value. Check your output again

Comment: Oha!! Yes. Sorry it is 0.  Output will be look like...                                                                  
 NP      NT        CT
Polaromonas   21      0         0
uncultured    67      0         0
Leptothrix    32      0         0
Clostridium   23      0        12
Methylocystis 34      0         23

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a script.sh and run **./script.sh first second**

```
#!/bin/bash

TOFIND=($(cat "$1" | tail -n +2))
COLUMNS=()
for ((I=0; I<3; ++I))
do
  COLUMNS+=("$(cat "$2" | tail -n +3 | awk -F' ' '{print $'$((2*$I+1))',$'$((2*$I+2))'}')")
done

RESULT=()

echo -e "\tNP\tNT\tCT"
for ELEM in "${TOFIND[@]}"
do
  echo -ne "$ELEM"
  for COLUMN in "${COLUMNS[@]}"
  do
    VAL="$(echo "$COLUMN" | grep "$ELEM")"
    if test -z "$VAL"
    then
      VAL=0
    else
      VAL="$(echo "$VAL" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')"
    fi
    echo -ne "\t$VAL"
  done
  echo ""
done
```

Comment: It is showing an following error.......                                                                                                                                                      $ ./script.sh first.csv second.csv >output.csv
./script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/script.sh: line 5: `for ((I=0; I<3; ++I))

Comment: This is because of a bad copy/paste that inserted a wrong newline character. Try to replace it.

Comment: Hi, I have copied script correctly..and running with following command ./script.sh first.csv second.csv output.csv                                                                   but still i have error, please help..                                                                                                                                                     $ ./script.sh first.csv second.csv >outfile.txt
./script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/script.sh: line 5: `for ((I=0; I<3; ++I))

Comment: – this not just showing here, it is not in script..